# How to concentrate function arguments into a vector in R by a function?

Tags: r, function, vector

I have some R-function `f`, which fixes some parameters of some other function `target` (thanks to [GKi for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566677/how-to-create-a-function-that-returns-a-function-with-fixed-parameters-in-r)):

```r
target <- function(b1,b2,l1,l2,l3,o1,o2) return((b1+b2+l1+l2+l3+o1+o2)^2)

fixed <- c(b1 = 1, l1 = 2, l2 = 3, l3 = 4, o1 = 5)
variable <- c("o2","b2")

f <- function(fixed, variable) {
  target_new <- function() {}
  formals(target_new) <- setNames(rep(list(bquote()), length(variable)), variable) 
  
  for(i in variable) assign(i, as.symbol(i))
  body(target_new) <- do.call("call", unlist(list("target", mget(variable), as.list(fixed))))
  
  return(target_new)
}

f(fixed,variable)
> function (o2, b2) 
> target(o2 = o2, b2 = b2, b1 = 1, l1 = 2, l2 = 3, l3 = 4, o1 = 5)
> <environment: 0x0000020a8e0c0c88>
```

I want to maximize `target_new` by nlm, so I need to concentrate its function arguments into a vector, i.e. the desired output of `f(fixed,variable)` is

```r
> function (theta) 
> target(o2 = theta[1], b2 = theta[2], b1 = 1, l1 = 2, l2 = 3, l3 = 4, o1 = 5)
```

How to modify the above code, so that the function can process the vector `theta`?

Please mind that the vectors `fixed` and `variable` can be of variable lengths.

Comment: How about the use of `...` in parameter definition such as `target <- function(...) {
  sum(...) ^ 2
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making this too complicated.

```
f <- function(fixed, variable) {

  function(theta) {
    args <- c(as.list(theta), as.list(fixed))
    names(args)[seq_along(variable)] <- variable
    do.call(target, args)
  }

}

fun <- f(fixed, variable)

#does it work?
all.equal(
  nlm(fun, p = c(1, 2)),
  nlm(function(theta) target(1,theta[2], 2, 3, 4, 5, theta[1]),
    p = c(1, 2))
)
#[1] TRUE
```