# Function that returns function with argument

Tags: r, functional-programming

How should I go about when creating a function that should return a function that includes an argument of the original function?

Consider for instance this function:

```r
a <- function(value){
  function(x) x + value
}
```

I'd like it to return the value I specify in the parameter in the resulting function, like this:

```r
b <- a(3)
#> b
#> function(x) x + 3
```

And be able to use the resulting function `b` thereafter:

```r
b(2)
#[1] 5
```

Instead, I get:

```r
> b
function(x) x + value
<environment: 0x000002254f80a758>
```

I've tried using `substitute`, `eval`, `parse`... but I'm a bit confused. Preferably a base R solution.

Comment: But your not saying x = 100,  a <- function(value) { function(x) x+3 return(value)} ? a(3)
[1] 3
a(3100)
[1] 3100

Comment: Your function already works. a(3)(4) gives 7.

Comment: [Some background](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html) about the environments used to evaluate the arguments

Comment: I have seen this question before, can't find it now. Here is another one which might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67566677/680068

Comment: @G.Grothendieck this is true! But I'm still confused, why is the true value of `value` not showing up in the output, and why is it working even though the value of `value` is not specified in any environment (at least not the global)?

Comment: R functions look up objects that are referenced but not defined in the function itself by looking in the environment in which the function was defined so when `value` is not found in the inner function it gets it from the outer function.  The environment in the outer function is not destroyed when the outer function exits since there is still a reference to it.

Comment: I get b(2)
[1] 5, where ab
function(value) {
function(x) x + value
}
 b <- ab(3), b
function(x) x + value
<bytecode: 0x5574a7311690>
<environment: 0x5574a7234680>, b(2)
[1] 5, so your b is correct, then you use it as b(additional_value), that was first demonstrated in a(3)(4), here substituting b for a(3).

Comment: You can use `ls.str(envir = environment(b))` to see all the objects inside the environment of function `b`. In this case, the result is `value :  num 3`. Therefore, function `b` executes with `value = 3` in **its** environment. You can even do `environment(b)$value <- 10; b(2) #12`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I discussed in the comments the function shown in the question already works so the approaches below are not really needed but if you want to create a function with the value of `value` hard coded into it then one of these. No packages are used.

**1) do.call/substitute**

```
a <- function(value, envir = parent.frame()) {
  f <- function(x) x + value
  body(f) <- do.call("substitute", list(body(f), list(value = value)))
  environment(f) <- envir
  f
}

b <- a(3)
b
## function (x) 
## x + 3

b(4)
## [1] 7

lapply(1:3, a, envir = environment())
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
function (x) 
x + 1L

[[2]]
function (x) 
x + 2L

[[3]]
function (x) 
x + 3L
```

**2) strings** Another possibility is to use string substitution:

```
a2 <- function(value, envir = parent.frame()) {
  eval(parse(text = gsub("\\bvalue\\b", value, "function(x) x + value")), envir)
}

lapply(1:3, a2, envir = environment())
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
function(x) x + 1

[[2]]
function(x) x + 2

[[3]]
function(x) x + 3
```

Comment: In the case of creating multiple functions through a loop, e.g. with `lapply(1:3, a)`, it gets impossible to recognize which function is which, hence the question. But your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh but now I realize that your answer is not optimal either in a `lapply` call... This is harder than I thought!